# Aws Php SDk - Create Cloudfront distribution using hard-coded credentials

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront, aws-php-sdk

I'm trying to create a cloudfront distribution while doing the authentication via hardcoded credentials.

However i receive this error when i run my code
*Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials*

It seems that the aws sdk is trying to authentificate using the second method listed here ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html ) - the one when you put the credentials in ./aws folder

Here is my code (taken from aws documentation ) - Any idea why this is not working ?

```
public function create_cloudfront_client(){

    $region='us-east-1';   
    $client = new Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient([
        'profile' => 'default',
        'version'       =>  'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-east-1', 
         'debug' => true,
        'credentials' =>[
                    'key'    => $this->aws_key,
                    'secret' => $this->aws_secret,
                    ],
              ]);

    $originName = 'cloudfrontme';
    $s3BucketURL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudfrontme';
    $callerReference = 'uniquestring99';
    $comment = 'Created by AWS SDK for PHP';
    $cacheBehavior = [

        'AllowedMethods' => [
            'CachedMethods' => [
                'Items' => ['HEAD', 'GET'],
                'Quantity' => 2,
            ],
            'Items' => ['HEAD', 'GET'],
            'Quantity' => 2,
        ],
        'Compress' => false,
        'DefaultTTL' => 0,
        'FieldLevelEncryptionId' => '',
        'ForwardedValues' => [
            'Cookies' => [
                'Forward' => 'none',
            ],
            'Headers' => [
                'Quantity' => 0,
            ],
            'QueryString' => false,
            'QueryStringCacheKeys' => [
                'Quantity' => 0,
            ],
        ],
        'LambdaFunctionAssociations' => ['Quantity' => 0],
        'MaxTTL' => 0,
        'MinTTL' => 0,
        'SmoothStreaming' => false,
        'TargetOriginId' => $originName,
        'TrustedSigners' => [
            'Enabled' => false,
            'Quantity' => 0,
        ],
        'ViewerProtocolPolicy' => 'allow-all',
    ];

    $enabled = false;
    $origin = [
        'Items' => [
            [
                'DomainName' => $s3BucketURL,
                'Id' => $originName,
                'OriginPath' => '',
                'CustomHeaders' => ['Quantity' => 0],
                'S3OriginConfig' => ['OriginAccessIdentity' => ''],

            ],
        ],
        'Quantity' => 1,
    ];



    $distribution = [
        'CallerReference' => $callerReference,
        'Comment' => $comment,
        'DefaultCacheBehavior' => $cacheBehavior,
        'Enabled' => $enabled,
        'Origins' => $origin,

    ];

    try {
        $result = $client->createDistribution([
            'DistributionConfig' => $distribution, //REQUIRED
        ]);
        var_dump($result);
    } catch (AwsException $e) {
        // output error message if fails
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete solution as an answer, below... or delete the question if you aren't certain how you fixed it and can no longer reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create the cloudfront client like this

```
 $client =  Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient::factory(array(
        'region' => $bucket_region,
        'version' => 'latest',

        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => $this->aws_key,
            'secret' => $this->aws_secret,
            ]

    ));
```

However i don't understand why this version works while the one below  (from aws docs ) does not. Can anyone explain this ? 
Thanks

```
$client = new Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient([
    'version'       =>  'latest',
    'region' => $bucket_region,
     'debug' => true,
    'credentials' =>[
                'key'    => $this->aws_key,
                'secret' => $this->aws_secret,
                ],
          ]);
```